# Is there a data structure in Java that can hold 4 or more values

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, hashmap

Is there a data structure in Java which can hold more than 4 values?

So something along the lines of

```
Map<String, String, String, String>;
```

This is needed to be able to reduce the number of if else statements I have. I would like to be able to do the following.

check if the data structure contains an element which matches a certain value, if it does then it assigns a link(which is string) to a variable and then adds a code and message to another variable which is related to that link.

if not is there a good workout around to achieve this?

Comment: No, but you can simply create your own. Or use a map with compound keys and values as collections if you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a data structure in Java which can hold more than 4 values?

There are lots of them.

The simplest is probably `String[]` which can hold 4 strings if you instantiate it like this:

```
new String[4]
```

And other Answers give other data structures that *might* meet your *actual* (i.e. unstated) requirements.

However, it is probably possible ... let alone sensible ... for us to enumerate all of the possible data structures that can meet your stated requirement.

Hint: you should try to explain how this data structure needs to work.

Hint 2: "the lines of `Map<String, String, String, String>`" does not help us understand your real requirement because we don't know what you mean by that.

---

**UPDATE** - Your explanation is still extremely vague, but I think you need something like this:

```
Map<String, MyRecord>;

public class MyRecord {
   private String link;
   private String code;
   private String message;

   // add constructor, getters, setters as required
}
```

Comment: I have edited my initial question to describe what it is needed for

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing in the standard libraries, but Guava has a nice implementation; called

[Multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

If Guava is not an option in your environment, you will have to re-invent the wheel though.

Answer (score 2):

Use can use MultiMap on Apache,

A MultiMap is a Map with slightly different semantics. Putting a value into the map will add the value to a Collection at that key. Getting a value will return a Collection, holding all the values put to that key

```
MultiMap mhm = new MultiValueMap();
mhm.put(key, "A");
mhm.put(key, "B");
mhm.put(key, "C");
Collection coll = (Collection) mhm.get(key);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Map of map:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, It seams like you simply need a 'key-value' pair. Key being a 'String', which you have referred as 'a certain value' in your question. Value is a kind of wrapper object wrapping three Strings which you have referred as 'link, code and message'.

I suggest you can simply use

```
HashMap < String, Wrapper >  map;
```

You can create a class ' Wrapper.java' which can contain three Strings, as instance fields

```
String link,code,message;
```

You can instantiate these fields in constructor and later can retrieve them using getter methods or also can have setters to set the values you need. You can provide a better contextual name to the class 'Wrapper.java'.